# Override default drupal_set_message() on node creation

Tags: forms

I am creating a simple basic module that alters the text of a submit button and should change the default creation message with `drupal_set_message()`.

I've found [an example about changing the message](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/overwriting-node-has-been-createdupdated-drupal-set-messages), and changed the code a little.

```
 function ask_admin_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   if ($form_id == "vragen_node_form") {
     $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Stel Uw Vraag';
     $form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][0] = 'ask_admin_node_form_submit';
   }
 }

 function ask_admin_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   global $user;

   $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
   $insert = empty($node->nid);
   node_save($node);
   $node_link = l(t('view'), 'node/'. $node->nid);
   $watchdog_args = array('@type' => $node->type, '%title' => $node->title);
   $t_args = array('@type' => node_get_types('name', $node), '%title' => $node->title);

   if ($insert) {
     watchdog('content', '@type: added %title.', $watchdog_args, WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $node_link);
     drupal_set_message(t('Uw vraag is met succes ontvangen en zal zo spoedig mogelijk beantwoord worden.', $t_args));
   }
   else {
     watchdog('content', '@type: updated %title.', $watchdog_args, WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $node_link);
     drupal_set_message(t('U heeft uw vraag met succes gewijzigd.', $t_args));
   }
   if ($node->nid) {
     unset($form_state['rebuild']);
     $form_state['nid'] = $node->nid;
     $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/'. $node->nid;
   }
   else {
     // In the unlikely case something went wrong on save, the node will be
     // rebuilt and node form redisplayed the same way as in preview.
     drupal_set_message(t('Er ging iets mis bij het verzenden van uw vraag.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

Although the form button is indeed changed to my own text, the message won't change when the node is created.

When I copy and paste the whole tutorial, my node messages won't change, but I also get no error messages.

Does anyone knows what is wrong, or how I can change the message using other code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `$form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][0]` to `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][0]` in your `HOOK_form_alter()`.

I don't know why that tutorial has you modifying the `$form['buttons']` array. Very few forms will put something as important as the primary Submit button outside of `$form['actions']`, and certainly not a core form.

Comment: Thanx man!!! Worked like a charm. To bad i can't accept the answer yet(someone else can?) neither can i vote up. So if anyone reads this, please give eclecto some points.

Answer (score 1):

This: `$form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][0] = 'ask_admin_node_form_submit';`

Should be this: `$form['#submit'] = array('ask_admin_node_form_submit');` if you want to completely override default form processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the message with https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages with a regex rule like:

```
Vraag .*? has been created.
```

or if translated

```
Vraag .*? is aangemaakt.
```

Then add your own custom message with Rules or with drupal_set_message() in a HOOK_form_alter()